# How to ignore or remove corrupt files in a zip in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, unzip, python-zipfile

I have a large zip file (40 GB) and I am trying to extract it. But some files are corrupted. Therefore whenever I try to `extractall()` I get `BadZipfile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'filename.jpg'` error. When I use `testzip()`, I am able to see the first corrupt file.
Here is the code I am using:

```
import zipfile

path_to_zip_file = "data.zip"
directory_to_extract_to = "directory/"

with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
   print(zip_ref.testzip())
   zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
```

Now my question is, is there a way to ignore or remove the corrupted file so that I continue my unzipping process?

Answer (score 1):

Extract files one by one, catch possible exceptions and continue with the next file:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("data.zip", "r") as zip_ref:
    for name in zip_ref.namelist():
        try:
            zip_ref.extract(name, "directory/")
        except zipfile.BadZipFile as e:
            print(e)
```